# How to customize the jquery autocomplete search mechanism

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I want to customize the search behavior of jquery autocomplete, the existing code is below

```
var data    = [

       {"url":"http://site/test.php",    "label":" test course"}]

             $k(".input").autocomplete({
            max:10,
            source: data,
            multipleSeparator: " ",
            select: function( event, ui ) { 
                window.location.href = ui.item.url;
            },
            appendTo: "#results",
            open: function() {
                var position = $("#results").position(),
                    left = position.left, top = position.top;

                $("#results > ul").css({left: left + 20 + "px",
                                        top: top + 4 + "px" });

            }
        });
```

I need to ignore the white spaces in data (search data).

suppose if i type "testcourse", i must get the result like  "test course".

How to do this.

Comment: A soon as you type "test", "test course" should be in the options list. If you're going to type the whole thing out, you're going to need to modify the 'data` source items as they are returned. Perhaps a custom join.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate any values in `data` that have white-space with the same entry with only the `label` being different (without white-space).

```
var data    = [
   {"url":"http://site/test.php",  "label":" test course"},
   {"url":"http://site/test.php",  "label":" testcourse"}
];
```

Here's a way you can loop through `data` and add any items that are not the same when you strip out white-spaces:

```
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var noWhsp = data[i].label.replace(/\s/g, '');
    if(data[i].label !== noWhsp){
        data.push({"url":data[i].url,  "label":noWhsp})
    }
}
```

Comment: But the duplicates will be shown suppose if i type "test" I get results like "test course" and "testcourse", Which is redundant and pretty confusing for users, Is there any alternatives for this to avoid the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another json value in data without whitespace.

```
var data    = [
   {"url":"http://site/test.php",  "label":" test course", "search_term":"testcourse"},
];
```

use search-term for seaching and display lable as a result

or

```
    var data    = [
       {"url":"http://site/test.php",  "label":" test course_testcourse"},
];
```

hear split lable value by "_" sign and search with label[1] and get result value label[0]

Comment: I just found the solution, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it, Code is below

```
$k("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
        max:10,
        source: function(req, responseFn) {
            var re = $k.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term).toUpperCase();
            re = re.replace(/\s+/g, "")
            var matcher = new RegExp(".*"+$.trim(re).replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "")+".*");
            var a = $k.grep( data, function(item,index){
                return matcher.test(item.label.toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, ""));
            });
         responseFn( a );
        },
        matchContains: true, 
        multipleSeparator: "",
        multiple: true,
        select: function( event, ui ) { 
            window.location.href = ui.item.url;
        },
        appendTo: "#results",
        open: function() {
            var position = $("#results").position(),
                left = position.left, top = position.top;

            $("#results > ul").css({left: left + 20 + "px",
                                    top: top + 4 + "px" });

        }
});
```